# Can i unscramble/ straighten out user data into my prefered input?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which i use to order materials needed for projects at work.

I just copy the data from the client into this sheet and it figures all sorts of things out.
The problem is that every client hands off the data in a different way. For example:

| Item | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Bike | Rims Ral 7035, Frame RGB 255/255/255 |
| car | Rims Sikkens R6.23.34, Frame RGB 230/010/255 |

How my clients give information:

| Item | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Bike | Frame RGB 255/255/255-Rims R6.23.34 |
| car | Rims 9016/ RGB 230 010 255 frame color |

Is there a way to look up any part of the string in a cell and compare it to my color database?
So if 7035 is recognized it know to put "Frame Ral" & "7035"

Does this make sense? And is there a way?

PS. obviously i can keep returning the files to clients if it doesnt match but i would like it if i could do it this way.

I tried something with isnumber(search("",A2)) but since the code is somewhere in that string, i dont know what to search for. Also the color codes have different lengths depending on the manufacturer.

Comment: I'm assuming the color needing to be pulled for vlookup into your color database is the `RGB 999/999/999` portion of the string? At any rate, there's likely not a way to do this with formulas. You could probably write up a UDF using the regex library in VBA to match the string with a regex pattern, but that's going to be daunting if you haven't programmed before.

Comment: Start by providing a template for your clients to fill in.

Comment: @freeflow they have it but... users... i dont know what else to say.

Comment: @JNevill The difficult part is that some codes have 4 digits, some have 5 or 6. UDF and Regex i will look into, thanks. I am definitly no programmer but i have done some VBA and VBS by just trying so maybe i can figure something out.

Comment: Yeah. It sounds like the usual for this type of exercise: Death from a thousand edge cases. You struggle through writing the code to parse out a substring, via regex, from a string and then you spend 10x that amount of time trying to narrow down every edge case by manipulating your regex pattern until you have an unparsable beast. Between the frustration of asking for a fixed file every time and the frustrating of writing this code and dealing with edge cases, you are in between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: The template should open a dialog box from which the relevant values can be selected from drop down lists.  The dialog box will ensure you get a  file filled out in the correct manner every time.

Comment: I wanted to keep my question short but in detail: I work for a somewhat small company where i order supplies. So sales people go to clients and make a list of what colors the client wants. My job is to copy the data into another excel file that we send to the manufacturer. When i started this job it was just that, copy paste and then manually change all data so its the right way for the manufacturor. With formulas and bits of vba i made it myself easier already but the main point is some sales write with points some with spaces or commas. They try but then instead they use a - as seporator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of a VBA function (that could be used as a udf) that will search the incoming cell's value for something that matches `RGB <number>/<number>/<number>` where the `/` could also be a space.

Note, this is just an example and it won't 100% solve your problem, but if you are serious about heading towards VBA to solve this, this should get you a jump start.

```
Function getColorCode(inCell As Range) As String
    'search incoming cell value for regex pattern and return first hit
    '
    'Add Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 via Tool>>References
    
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim pattern As String
    
    'write the regex pattern for matching color
    pattern = "RGB [0-9]{1,3}[/ ][0-9]{1,3}[/ ][0-9]{1,3}"
    
    'Set up the regex object properties
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
    End With
    
    'If we find a match, extract it and return
    If regEx.Test(inCell.Value) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(inCell.Value)
        getColorCode = matches(0)
    End If
    
End Function
```

In the VBA screen, you'll need to go to Tools>>References and find that `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` and put a checkbox next to it for this work. Then create a new module and paste this in. You can then save your workbook and use this in the sheet like `=getColorCode(A1)` where `A1` has a value like your example.

For some more information about regex in VBA check out the answers here: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) You can also search online since most dialects of regex are similar. That `pattern` string will be the part that needs the most tweaking to deal with as many edge cases as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be trying this and looking further into regex.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am looking at it now but is there a way to always output in a certain way? So even `rgb 12 123 456` would be returned as `RGB 012/123/456`.Would i need to do something like `getColorCode =UCASE(matches(0))` and for the spaces inbetween the values nest in another regex?

Comment: Oh sure. The sky is the limit. You'll likely want to throw more regex at it. Like if you get a match with the regex `rgb [0-9]{1,3} [0-9]{1,3} [0-9]{0-3}` Then you can capture that match and do something like `output = "RGB " & Join(Split(Replace(matches[0], "rgb ", ""), " "), "/")` It's just a lot of catching edge cases and string manipulation work.